# Adding labels on each bar in ggplot2 correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a barchart using `ggplot2`. I'm trying to add labels on each bar with its value, but for some odd reason it's going horribly wrong where two of the values appear on one bar. Any ideas on how to fix this/what I could be doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18717, 18717, 18717, 18747, 
18747, 18747, 18778, 18778, 18778), class = "Date"), Category = c("Total PSCE", 
"Businesses", "Households", "Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households", 
"Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households"), Forecast = c(2.3, 
3.5, 2.5, 3.4, 5.4, 3.7, 3.4, 5.1, 3.8)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data, aes(Date, Forecast, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Forecast), colour = "white", size = 3, vjust = 2, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is essentially that the scales of the plot in the x axis is continuous and so the usual width of 1 for position dodge is unsuitable as the 3 bars take up the space of nearly 30 days. I have tried replacing the width argument with 27. This solution had some success.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18717, 18717, 18717, 18747, 
                                          18747, 18747, 18778, 18778, 18778), class = "Date"), Category = c("Total PSCE", 
                                                                                                            "Businesses", "Households", "Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households", 
                                                                                                            "Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households"), Forecast = c(2.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3.5, 2.5, 3.4, 5.4, 3.7, 3.4, 5.1, 3.8)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
                                                                                                                                                                    ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data, aes(Date, Forecast, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(27)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Forecast), colour = "white", size = 3, vjust = 2, position = position_dodge(27))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

An alternate solution would be to make the month variable a categorical variable. I like to use the function `month()` from the lubridate package for this. I have demonstrated how this makes the widths 1 as expected below. (The `as.factor()` function could be used to acheive a similar effect).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18717, 18717, 18717, 18747, 
                                          18747, 18747, 18778, 18778, 18778), class = "Date"), Category = c("Total PSCE", 
                                                                                                            "Businesses", "Households", "Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households", 
                                                                                                            "Total PSCE", "Businesses", "Households"), Forecast = c(2.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3.5, 2.5, 3.4, 5.4, 3.7, 3.4, 5.1, 3.8)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
                                                                                                                                                                    ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data, aes(month(Date, label = T, abbr = T), Forecast, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Forecast), colour = "white", size = 3, vjust = 2, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you so much